# How to save regression coefficients to file in SAS?`

Tags: sas, output, logistic-regression

I am trying to carry out a logistic regression with SAS. I have few settings for the model, and try to compare the difference.

What I want to archieve is to output the estimated coefficients to a file. I think ODS maybe a promising way, but don't know how to use it.

Can anyone write me a simple example?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a bit of additional color; `ODS OUTPUT <NAME>=DATASET ... ;` will save the output  into the specified dataset.

Use `ODS TRACE` get the names of output tables.  Information on the tables will be written to the log.

```
ods trace on;
ods output ParameterEstimates=estimates;
proc logistic data=test;
model y = i;
run;
ods trace off;
```

Comment: Hi, DomPazz. Thanks for the answer. I think it works. I've also tried to commet out the trace statements, and it works all the same. Can you explain the effect of `trace on` and `trace off` please? Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Sure, `ODS TRACE ON;` tells the ODS system to echo to the log each output table that it delivers (ie prints to your output).  `ODS TRACE OFF;` turns off the echo to the log.

Answer (score 3):

For Logistic:

```
proc logistic data = in descending outest = out;
  class rank / param=ref ;
  model admit = gre gpa rank;
run;
```

For proc reg:

```
proc reg data=a;
   model y z=x1 x2;
   output out=b
run;
```

for proc glm:

```
ods output Solution=parameters FitStatistics=fit;
proc glm data=hers;
model glucose = exercise ;
quit;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

for proc reg this doesn't work for me

Use proc reg  OUTEST=b

```
proc reg data=a outest=b;
  model y=x1;
run;
```

other reg  can get other parameters added to OUTEST.

Comment: Hi there, how is this an answer to solve the problem?